# In MS Azure AD, I am trying to configure the SSO, but SSO option is not showing up under the selected Enterprise Application

Tags: azure, salesforce, single-sign-on, sfdc

I am configuring the Azure Active Directory as SSO Authentication Provider for Salesforce. I have already Registered the Application in Azure. When I try to configure SSO in Azure for the registered application but I am not able to see Single sign on option under Manage for the aplication. Please help.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-portal?

Comment: Hi Guru, if my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for responding. Actually it is more of a subscription issue. I am not able to add the add the 'New application' under Enterprise Application option. Once I get that solved then I will try your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to be a Global Administrator or Co-admin of that AD. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/access-panel-troubleshoot-application-not-appearing

Comment: Thank you Tony. My issue has been resolved. Actually, the team that handles the Azure has created the app for me and assigned me as a User. I will not request to have Global Admin or co-admin eole for future purposes.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the answer that helps you and vote it as helpful, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 5):

You need to choose Non-gallery application to add your own application.
Click Azure Active Directory->click Enterprise applications->click New application->choose Non-gallery application.
[image]

Then you will find the Single sign-on feature.
[image]